# Is there a term for two songs that are usually played consecutively?

Tags: terminology

Examples:

> 1. "We Will Rock You" and "We Are The Champions" by Queen
> 2. "Load Out" and "Stay" by Jackson Browne

Comment: Likely not the terminology or the answer, but "We Will Rock You" is the B-side song of "We Are The Champions".

Comment: I'm curious about this one as well. Another example is "The Happiest Days of Our Lives" and "Another Brick in the Wall, Pt. 2" by Pink Floyd.

Comment: The example of "We Will Rock You" and "We Are The Champions" ("Heartbreaker" and "Communication Breakdown" by Led Zeppelin, "Lovin' Touchin'" and "City of the Angels" by Journey, etc) where one track leads directly into another  are known in the radio biz are known as "Locked tracks." It was (among other reasons) a ploy to get more airtime for the band.

Comment: @Dekkadeci More relevantly, those two are the first tracks of the album _News of the World_.

Comment: @Duston _Communication Breakdown_ is from _Led Zeppelin 1_ and _Heartbreaker_ is from _Led Zeppelin II_, why would they be played together? Maybe you meant _Heartbreaker_ + _Living Loving Maid_? There's a pretty abrupt switch between those 2 tracks.

Comment: @Amarth My mistake, you're right, it is Living Loving Maid.

Comment: By ‘together’, does this mean songs that are usually played _consecutively_, rather than _simultaneously_…?

Comment: consecutively, always in the same order

Comment: Another example 'Home by the sea' and 'second home by the sea' by Genesis on the album they are continuous and when played live they're played together. Maybe they just split them on the album 'cos currently style was anti long songs ?

Answer (score 1):

There's not a specific term per se, but you might hear such songs referred to as a "**common pairing**" — not formal in any sense, but frequently used.

If the songs are combined such that they form, in effect, one longer song, it's a "**medley**". In a medley the songs come one after they other; whereas, in a "**mashup**" they could be consecutive, simultaneous, interleaved, or a combination thereof.

The transition between two songs in called a "**segue**". This can be musical, but also could be extra-musical (e.g., talking).

Answer (score 0):

A [**suite**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/suite#Noun) is a set of pieces of music that belong together, and are usually played in sequence.

That's mostly used for classical/‘serious’ music (and music originally written for movies/plays), where it usually refers to instrumental pieces; the vocal equivalent would probably be [**song cycle**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Song_cycle).

However, modern artists including [Steve Hillage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fish_Rising), [Prince](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scandalous!), [Synergy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolitan_Suite), [Sonny Rollins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_Suite_(Sonny_Rollins_album)), and [Mike Batt](https://www.discogs.com/release/767794-Mike-Batt-And-Friends-Tarot-Suite) have included suites on their albums — of songs as well as instrumentals.

Answer (score -2):

Quick answer

The term used to describe two songs usually sung together is polyphony. In music, the simultaneous combination of two or more tones or melodic lines (the term derives from the Greek word for “many sounds”). Thus, even a single interval made up of two simultaneous tones or a chord of three simultaneous tones is rudimentarily polyphonic. (“Polyphony | Definition, Melodic Lines, & Counterpoint | Britannica”) Table of Contents show What is it called when you combine 2 songs?

Comment: The question is intended to mean songs played consecutively rather than simultaneously.